# Error 409 when copy Azure Blob file within container with PHP

Tags: php, azure-blob-storage

Using PHP to connect to Azure blob storage account. Using [azure-storage-php](https://packagist.org/packages/microsoft/azure-storage-blob) ( [github](https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-php) )

For the copy i use `BlobRestProxy.copyBlob()` using the [api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894037.aspx).

I am able to connect to the azure blob storage. Able to upload, list, delete blob files. But not able to copy the blob file within the same container. Does anyone has an example of how to copy a blob file within php using azure-storage-php or does anyone recognizes the error?

I already tried it with several blob storage account settings (public and not). For authentication i use a Shared Access Signature. The weird thing is that i am able to do alle things like create, read and delete but copy does give the below error. Thanks in advance.

The storage account is new, created at 3-12-2021

```
Fail:
Code: 409
Value: Public access is not permitted on this storage account.
details (if any): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code><Message>Public access is not permitted on this storage account.
RequestId:4b324b08-b01e-0009-6c1e-1187a1000000
Time:2022-01-24T12:30:35.8956602Z</Message></Error>.
```

Thanks for the reply allready!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

The **Shared Access Signature** specified on the request applies only to the destination blob while using Copy Blob

**Access to the source blob is authorized separately**

If you are using the shared key (Storage Account Key), the authorization would have been done with the same key

As you are using Shared Access Signature, you need to append the SAS token in the **x-ms-copy-source** in the request

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That was allready helpfull. Tomorow we will test it again. I was allready able to get it to work. There for i had to set the configuration of the storage account to "Allow Blob public access" and i had to set the same for the test container i used. But enable public access is not what we want so we need to solve the authorization issue. When this issue is solved i will leaf a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RamaraoAdapa-MT, your answer was very helpfull. The developer has fixed the problem now.
And it was indeed the case that if you use the storage account key the copy is done with the same key. Public access is not necessery in both cases (SAS or AccountKey)